# How to execute a terminal command every time the firefox windows closes

Tags: command-line, bash, firefox

I need to execute this:

```
rm -rf ~/.wine-pipelight/*;
rm -rf ~/.wine-pipelight/./.*;
cp -a ~/viewright_backup/. ~/.wine-pipelight
```

every time the Firefox window closes. But not necessarily when all the windows closed, but on every window that is closed.
For example, if I have one Firefox window and one Firefox pop-up window. If I close at least one windows, I want to execute this command. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It would most probably be easier to solve the issue than using such a workaround. Which Pipelight and wine-compholio version do you use?

Comment: I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyRspjFLGlYr) toutorial. it's in serbian, but there are codes used in the description.

Comment: It's one service of Serbia broadband company which is not oficially supported on linux.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way I can think of is not very elegant. You can have a script running in the background that counts the number of open firefox windows every second and launches your command if that number changes. Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


## Run firefox
/usr/bin/firefox &

## Initialize the variable to 100
last=100;

## Start infinite loop, it will run while there
## is a running firefox instance.
while pgrep firefox >/dev/null;
do
    ## Get the number of firefox windows    
    num=$(xdotool search --name firefox | wc -l)

    ## If this number is less than it was, launch your commands
    if [ "$num" -lt "$last" ]
    then
        rm -rf ~/.wine-pipelight/*;
        ## I included this since you had it in your post but it
        ## does exactly the same as the command above.
        rm -rf ~/.wine-pipelight/./.*;
        cp -a ~/viewright_backup/. ~/.wine-pipelight      
    fi

    ## Save the number of windows as $last for next time
    last=$num

    ## Wait for a second so as not to spam your CPU.
    ## Depending on your use, you might want to make it wait a bit longer,
    ## the longer you wait, the lighter the load on your machine
    sleep 1

done
```

Save the script above as `firefox`, put it in your `~/bin` directory and make it executable `chmod a+x ~/bin/firefox`. Since Ubuntu adds `~/bin` to your `$PATH` by default and adds it before any other directories, running `firefox` will launch that script instead of the normal firefox executable. Now, because the script is launching `/usr/bin/firefox`, this means that your normal firefox will appear, just as you expect, only with the script running as well. The script will exit as soon as you close firefox.

DISCLAIMER:

This script is

1. Not elegant, it needs to be run as an infinite loop in the background.
2. Requires `xdotool`, install it with `sudo apt-get install xdotool`
3. Does not work for tabs, only windows.

Comment: nice workaround

Comment: Thanks! I won't make it autostart, but rather make it start when firefox starts. Thanks you very much, I'll try it.

Comment: @terdon Since I'm planing to make it start when firefox starts, is it possible to make it stop when firefox is closed. Maybe something like: `while ["0" -lt "$(xdotool search --name firefox | wc -l)"   ]`. I don't know if sintax is right but you get the point... Could you rewrite it to meet this condition? Thanks!

Comment: @DusanMilosevic see updated answer. I rewrote it so that the script itself launches firefox and only runs as long as at least one firefox instance is running.