# In this script, ~ is /root/. How to be in /home/name-of-the-user/?

Tags: bash, scripts, home-directory

```
#!/bin/bash    

#become root
UID=$(id -u)
if [ x$UID != x0 ] 
then
    printf -v cmd_str '%q ' "$0" "$@"
    exec sudo su -c "$cmd_str"
fi


mkdir ~/.D3GO/; 
cp -a `pwd`/viewright_backup/. ~/.D3GO/;

mkdir /opt/D3GO/;
cp `pwd`/D3GO /opt/D3GO/;
cp `pwd`/D3GO.png /opt/D3GO/;
cp `pwd`/D3GO.desktop /usr/share/applications/;
chmod +x /opt/D3GO/D3GO;
```

As you can see, because this uses ~, and the script is ran as root, it creats the folder.D3GO in the /root/ directory. Is it possible to create it in the home directory. For example, if the script is located in /home/user/Downloads/, it should create the directory in home/user/. If it's located in /home/user2/Downloads/dir/, it should create it in /home/user2/ etc. Is this possible? Thanks!

Maybe something like:

```
#!/bin/bash    

#remember the username
user = $(whoami);

#become root
UID=$(id -u)
if [ x$UID != x0 ] 
then
    printf -v cmd_str '%q ' "$0" "$@"
    exec sudo su -c "$cmd_str"
fi


mkdir /home/`echo user`/.D3GO/; 
cp -a `pwd`/viewright_backup/. /home/`echo user`/.D3GO/;
```

Comment: Don't become root, use `sudo` for each line, and explicitly specify `/root` instead of `~`.

Comment: No, no, I'm not trying to create ./D3GO in /root/.

Comment: Why do you insist in using /home/? Toss those files in /opt/D3GO/ or /usr/local/(bin/).

Comment: @DusanMilosevic: My bad. My brain twisted something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making this more difficult then it needs to be.

First, there is no reason your script (as posted) needs to run as root.

Second, you are using /opt rather then /usr/local . By default , ubuntu uses /usr/local and /usr/local is on the default path.

And third your are using ambiguous locations such as .. and pwd and ~ . It is best to use the full path and standard locations.

Why not use $HOME ?

[[ -d "$HOME"/.D3GO ]] || mkdir "$HOME"/.D3GO

Most of your other problems are solved with a decent make file or a well packaged .deb . If your script is dependent on things outside the script, files or .png, package it into a .deb or write a make file so that the things you need are installed into standard locations /usr/local or in the system if you wish.

If you are installing something, you would provide an archive and you should write your script relative to the archive you provide.

So your archive might be FOO and inside you would have

FOO/files
FOO/img
FOO/Your_script

So "Your_Script" can just call "cp ./file/file_to_install /where/to/install"

To be honest, most of your installation ("cp pwd" stuff) is best handled with either

1. Proper packaging into a .deb
2. A make file .

Either of the above have numerous advantages including, but not limited to, ease of installation, ease of removal, and installing files to standard, known locations.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know anything about deb files, and my second code looks ok to me at least. I know a little about scripts. So, I'm trying to "install" [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/492340/how-to-execute-a-terminal-command-every-time-the-firefox-windows-closes) script.

Comment: Well, again , your lack of knowledge is half your problem. Rather then using standard locations and install techniques you are re-inventing the wheel without really understanding what a wheel should look like. I highly suggest you use Standard locations ( /usr/local ) and at a minimum start with an archive with a known starting layout. Trying to move $random_files from $random_locations and ending up in /root should all suggest you are off on the wrong foot.

Comment: sorry it that came across as a bit harsh, that was not my intention. I outlined a basic archive structure that would greatly simplify your script. The use of standard locations , keeping files on the $PATH and standard locations also helps. No need to copy shared files into each user $HOME , just put them in /usr/local/bin or what not.

Comment: No, no, I didn't get offended. I really meant "Thank you!" for giving me an advice. I always listen to advices especially if they come from someone experienced.

Comment: The problem is that, I cannot use the standard locations because these scripts should fix the problem with file that is located in ~/.wine-pipelight/ and I'm trying to make a file that will help other people in my country, because the most famous TV provider won't support linux with D3GO(the TV via internet) etc. Long story... Maybe I simply doesn't have the knowledge to make it work for others... I  managed to make it work,but it's hard to install and set up :(

Comment: @DusanMilosevic I have seen other questions from you about this. Perhaps you should ask a question that starts at the beginning: what have you done so far, how have you done it, and ask how it can be provided to others. Perhaps we could be able to tackle some problems at an earlier stage so that distribution becomes easier.

Comment: @DusanMilosevic so you have a directory, .wine-pipelight . You need to copy $some_things from that directory and make them available for all users? So copy $some_things to the proper location in /usr/local. Official packages in the ubuntu repositories use `/usr/share/applications/` for desktop files. Custom apps use `/usr/local/share/applications` for desktop fioles. And since /usr/local is in the default Ubuntu $PATH, if you place a .desktop file there, it is available for all users.

Comment: So `sudo cp .wine-pipelight/whatever/your.desktop /usr/local/share/applications`and on for your files.. As suggested by @muru , and myslef earlier, start by making a list of files you need to copy, then figure out where to put them (hint /opt is a really bad choice in Ubuntu) , then your script is simple, from you post it is merely copying 2 known files to an appropriate location (hint use /usr/local )

Comment: @DusanMilosevic - so if you put the files in the proper location, in /usr/local , you do NOT need to make a directory per user in $HOME.

Comment: I figured it out. I didn't need to become root. Instead, when I needed superuser permissions, u just put sudo in fronnt of the command, and now everything works. Thanks!